# Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.13.1/darwin-x64-72_binding.node

Tags: apache-dolphinscheduler

when compile front-end code(dolphinscheduler-ui), you may meet this problem:[ERROR] Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.13.1/darwin-x64-72_binding.node":

Answer (score 0):

cd dolphinscheduler-ui

1. delete node_modules directory
   sudo rm -rf node_modules
2. install node-sass through npm.taobao.org
   sudo npm uninstall node-sass
   sudo npm i node-sass --sass_binary_site=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/node-sass/

if the 2 step failure, please
sudo npm rebuild node-sass

referer url: https://dolphinscheduler.apache.org/zh-cn/docs/1.2.0/user_doc/frontend-development.html

By the way:
when solved this problem, if you don't want to download this node every time, you can set system environment variable： SASS_BINARY_PATH= /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.node